# Change displayed price based on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-content

Really hope someone can help with this.

I am building a site and need to be able to have people display a price based on their preferred option.

To see what I mean, please look at this link where it is done perfectly: https://swiftype.com/pricing

...when people select monthly or yearly, the displayed price in the chart beneath changes dynamically and instantly (without page reload).

This is what I need (except with three option to choose, not one). I suspect it is jquery with dynamic divs, but I cannot make it happen.

If anyone can help, I would be so so grateful.

Best wishes, and thanks for your time. AB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// make the billing period selected tabs work
    $(function() {
      var $pricingTable = $('#pricing-table');
      $('#billing-picker .tab').click(function() {
        var $selectedTab = $(this);
        var selectedPeriod = $selectedTab.data('period-length');
        $('.tab').removeClass('selected');
        $selectedTab.addClass('selected');
        $pricingTable.removeClass().addClass(selectedPeriod);
      })
    });
```

This is the SCRIPT which does the selection of button ..

Comment: Thank you for helping out. 

I should have said that I have already inspected the elements. I have also got this js fiddle from elsewhere, which does the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/zFFEe/

But I just cannot get it working on my site... http://design4writers.wpengine.com/cover-design-portfolio ...I have tried all things.

Please see the bottom of this page, where I am just trying to get it working before styling it. The clicking is not working.

The site is in WordPress if that helps?

Thanks again for your time. Andrew.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  ..
Your JQuery file is not loaded...Plz check the url

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script> ..
WHAT IS 'JS library'..Give proper source..

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much. This is the first time I have used Stack Overflow and I am so thankful for you help! Is there a way to reward kudos etc? Either way, thank you for helping :)

Comment: I think I just did that (pressed the green tick and made it green).

Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Hi. I wonder if you can just help me to finish off my implementation? Please see this page: http://design4writers.wpengine.com/cover-design and scroll down to the pricing table. Under the heading 'Select your currency' there are buttons which work to change the displayed currency price. However, I am trying to change the currency in each of the four columns. It only changes the first one and, as you will see if you click on a currency button, the others disappear :(  

Again, any help greatly appreciated. Then I can finish off the styling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you provide, is using a monthly or yearly class to hide and show the divs that already contains the prices, without any Ajax call. Try to inspect the elements with firebug or other console and you will see by yourself how is working.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. 

I should have said that I have already inspected the elements. I have also got this js fiddle from elsewhere, which does the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/zFFEe/

But I just cannot get it working on my site... http://design4writers.wpengine.com/cover-design-portfolio ...I have tried all things.

Please see the bottom of this page, where I am just trying to get it working before styling it. The clicking is not working.

The site is in WordPress if that helps?

Thanks again for your time. Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have an empty div which, on button click loads ajax content dynamically. If it's always going to be the same content, than I would suggest just have three divs and simply hiding the ones that are not being shown.

Have a look into the Jquery 'hide' method.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for helping out. 

I should have said that I have already inspected the elements. I have also got this js fiddle from elsewhere, which does the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/zFFEe/

But I just cannot get it working on my site... http://design4writers.wpengine.com/cover-design-portfolio ...I have tried all things.

Please see the bottom of this page, where I am just trying to get it working before styling it. The clicking is not working.

The site is in WordPress if that helps?

Thanks again for your time. Andrew.